# ReactJS and AWS-S3 Upload from the client side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a single page application built with ReactJS and MobX for the front end part, and ruby on rails for the backend part. I have an image drop zone container, and I want the user to be able to upload images, but all the uploading implementation to be done in the front-end part, and the backend only will receive the URL from the uploaded image. Is it possible to accomplish this with ReactJS without involving the server at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a concept called as `direct upload` which you can use to do this. Here is an article by heroku to do this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails

You can also look into the gem `carrierwave direct` https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct

You might also want to check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html
and 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s3-uploader

If you are willing to use a easy to use managed service filestack.com is a good option.